# wget: How can I download files but no folders via FTP?

Tags: bash, ftp, wget

I need to download the files located in the root of in my FTP server, but not the folders, is there a way to do that?

I'm currently connecting with this string:

```
wget --timeout 20 -m -nH --user "user" --password "pass" ftp://123.123.com
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

wget doesn't have filtering capabilities.
However you can create a simple script to collect the files first and then get them using wget.

```
echo open $HOST > ftp.txt
echo user $USER $PASS >> ftp.txt
echo ls >> ftp.txt
echo bye >> ftp.txt
ftp < ftp.txt | awk '^-' | awk '{print $9}' > files.txt
wget --timeout 20 -m -nH --user "user" --password "pass" -i files.txt ftp://123.123.com
```

Comment: This one doesn't work, it saves the `ls` of the folder I'm at instead of the server one

Comment: sorry. fixed the line: echo ls >> ftp.txt

Comment: Like this it doesn't connect to ftp, I think the `ftp.txt` is bad. Maybe it isn't the format? It opens the conection but doesn't input user and password (I've done it manually and nothing happens)